# Excel VBA - Search for dates and copy specific cells to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code which was written by a previous coworker, and I need help modifying this.

A Userform is loaded, and a start/end date is inputted by the user. It searches Sheet 1 for dates within this start/end range, and then copies that entire row to Sheet2, and continues down Sheet1 searching for matching dates.

I need to modify this to

1. search `Sheet1`, Column `Q` and `S` for dates
2. copy `Sheet1` cells `C`, `G`, `J` and the dates `Q`, and `S` in this same row
3. paste to a row on `Sheet2` in columns `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and `E`.

It's over my knowledge level. Any help would be appreciated, as I can't seem to figure this code out. If you could explain how this works in simple terms, that would be equally awesome!

```
Dim rng As Range, destRow As Long
    Dim shtSrc As Worksheet, shtDest As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range '-- this is used to store the single cell in the For Each loop

    Set shtSrc = Sheets("Sheet1") ' Sets "Sheet1" sheet as source sheet
    Set shtDest = Sheets("Sheet2") 'Sets "Sheet2." sheet as destination sheet
    destRow = 5 'Start copying to this row on destination sheet

' >> Set range to search for dates in Look Ahead period <<
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(shtSrc.Range("P:P"), shtSrc.UsedRange)

' >> Look for matching dates in columns C to D <<
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If (c.value >= startDate And c.value <= endDate) Or _
    (c.Offset(0, 1).value >= startDate And c.Offset(0, 1).value <= endDate) Then ' Does date fall between start and end dates? If Yes, then copy to destination sheet

            c.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, 12).Copy _
                          shtDest.Cells(destRow, 1) 'Copy a 12 cell wide block to the other sheet, paste into Column A on row destRow
            destRow = destRow + 1

' > Ends search for dates <
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code and it should work:

```
Dim rng As Range, destRow As Long
Dim shtSrc As Worksheet, shtDest As Worksheet
Dim c As Range '-- this is used to store the single cell in the For Each loop

Set shtSrc = Sheets("Sheet1") ' Sets "Sheet1" sheet as source sheet
Set shtDest = Sheets("Sheet2") 'Sets "Sheet2." sheet as destination sheet
destRow = 5 'Start copying to this row on destination sheet

' >> Set range to search for dates in Look Ahead period <<
Set rng = Application.Intersect(shtSrc.Range("Q:Q"), shtSrc.UsedRange)

' >> Look for matching dates in columns C to D <<
For Each c In rng.Cells
    If (c.Value >= StartDate And c.Value <= EndDate) Or _
(c.Offset(0, 2).Value >= StartDate And c.Offset(0, 2).Value <= EndDate) Then ' Does date fall between start and end dates? If Yes, then copy to destination sheet

        shtSrc.Range("C" & c.Row).Copy shtDest.Range("A" & destRow)
        shtSrc.Range("G" & c.Row).Copy shtDest.Range("B" & destRow)
        shtSrc.Range("J" & c.Row).Copy shtDest.Range("C" & destRow)
        shtSrc.Range("Q" & c.Row).Copy shtDest.Range("D" & destRow)
        shtSrc.Range("S" & c.Row).Copy shtDest.Range("E" & destRow)

        destRow = destRow + 1

' > Ends search for dates <
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an "Excel-as-datasource" problem, I would use an SQL statement for this. Add a reference to **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library** (via **Tools** -> **References...**). There may be versions other than 6.1; choose the highest.

```
Dim pathToExcelFile As String
pathToExcelFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name

Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=""" & pathToExcelFile & """;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No"""

'This string defines which data we are retrieving from the source worksheet
'SELECT F3, F7, F10, F17, F19 -- choose the columns C, G, J, Q and S
'FROM [Sheet1$] -- from Sheet1
'WHERE ... -- where F17 (Column Q) is between the start and end date;
'    we'll fill in the values corresponding to the question marks later
'OR ... -- or F19 (Column S) is between the start and end date

cmd.CommandText = _
    "SELECT F3, F7, F10, F17, F19 " & _
    "FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
    "WHERE F17 BETWEEN ? AND ? " & _
       "OR F19 BETWEEN ? AND ?"

Dim startParameter As ADODB.Parameter
Set startParameter = cmd.CreateParameter("StartDate", adDate, adParamInput, , StartDate)

Dim endParameter As ADODB.Parameter
Set endParameter = cmd.CreateParameter("EndDate", adDate, adParamInput, , EndDate)

'We're filling in the question marks here
'1st and 3rd -- start date
'2nd and 4th -- end date
cmd.Paramters.Append startParameter
cmd.Parameters.Append endParameter
cmd.Paramters.Append startParameter
cmd.Parameters.Append endParameter

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = cmd.Execute

'Paste the resulting data starting from A5
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A5").CopyFromRecordset(rs)
```

---

#### References

ActiveX Data Objects

- [**Command** object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/command-object-ado?view=sql-server-2017), [**ActiveConnection** property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/activeconnection-property-ado?view=sql-server-2017), [**CommandText** property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/commandtext-property-ado?view=sql-server-2017), [**CreateParameter** method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/createparameter-method-ado?view=sql-server-2017)
- [**Parameters** collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameters-collection-ado?view=sql-server-2017), [**Append** method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/append-method-ado?view=sql-server-2017)
- [**Recordset** object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/recordset-object-ado?view=sql-server-2017)

Excel

- [**Worksheets** collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheets-object-excel)
- [**Worksheet** object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-object-excel), [**Range** property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-range-property-excel), [**Cells** property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-cells-property-excel)
- [**Range** object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel), [**CopyFromRecordset** method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cec7fded-f4e0-1b1c-5374-8a860828c9cc%28office.15%29.aspx), [**TextToColumns** method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-texttocolumns-method-excel), [**Value** property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-value-property-excel)